# Reading Many CSV Files at the Same Time in R and Combining All into one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 20 .CSV files and all of them have equal number of row/col (1 row and 42 columns). I want to make a dataframe out of all them and have each CSV file as one row of my dataframe and have the name of the CSV file as my row name. Is it even possible to do this?

To illustrate this with an example:

```
A.csv
10 21 32 45

B.csv
33 45 93 90

C.csv
12 93 Na 21
```

Resulting dataframe I am looking for would be:

```
A 10 21 32 45
B 33 45 93 90
C 12 93 Na 21
```

Comment: If you gave -1 please clearly explain why.

Comment: I did not, but there are probably over 30 q&a's for this on SO. please show some minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

Both `data.table` (`rbindlist`) and `dplyr` (`bind_rows`) have functions to do this. My preferred solution would be to use `readr::read_csv` together with `dplyr::bind_rows` to do this:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  lapply(
    list.files(
      "path/to/csv_files", 
      pattern = ".csv", 
      full.names = TRUE
    ), 
    read_csv, 
    header = FALSE, 
    na_strings = c("Na")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `list.files()` function combined with `lapply` which loop through all the files and read them as data.frame. Finally, a `do.call(rbind ...` combine separate dataframes together:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(PathToCsvFile, pattern = ".csv", full.names = T), read.csv))
```

**Upadate**:

```
filePaths <- list.files(PathToCsvFile, pattern = ".csv", full.names = T)
cbind(gsub(".csv", "", basename(filePaths)), do.call(rbind, lapply(filePaths, read.csv)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for some reason this is not working and shows an error: `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'D38hz6lVkkxE.csv': No such file or directory` I checked the file and it is working perfectly fine and is not corrupted.

Comment: The PathToCsvFile should be the directory where your csv files are located.

Comment: You might need `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it looks like it was able to access the directory and find the name of the first file in that folder, I wrote the directory as `"C:/Documents/CSVs"`

Comment: Taking @RichardScriven's suggestion, specify the `full.names = T` in the `list.files()` function.

Comment: Both the answers ignored the requirement of having the source csv filename as in a column.

Comment: Adding `full.names=T` and 'header=FALSE` gave me good results, but as Frash mentioned I didn't get the CSV names to be the row names.

Comment: You can extract the file names and cbind with the data frame you just get. See the updated answer.

Comment: Just fyi, you don't have to explicitly specify the `header = F` since that is the default.

Comment: Not using `header=FALSE` gives me only one row!